# Delete Tire search index on destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire, destroy

I implemented elasticsearch and it seems to work fine except for when I want to delete a record of something. In my controller destroy method I can't seem to delete the index without doing `rake environment tire:import CLASS=Stream FORCE=true`

```
 def destroy
   #@stream = Stream.friendly.find(params[:id])
   #Stream.tire.index(@stream).delete
   #@stream.destroy

    @stream.destroy
    system "rake environment tire:import CLASS=Stream FORCE=true"

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to streams_url, notice: 'Stream was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

If I use the commented out code I get the error: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find all Streams with 'id': (1, 2, 3, 4) (found 2 results, but was looking for 4)):`

How are you supposed to delete the index properly along with @stream?

**EDIT** Model code

```
  class Stream < ActiveRecord::Base

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title

  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  def self.search(params)
    tire.search(load: true) do
      query { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:query].present?
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: This looks like there is an inconsistency between records in your DB and in Elasticsearch. Do you have tests/scripts that alter either your tables or Elasticsearch outside Tire?

Comment: My app also runs on heroku and when I use rake environment tire:import CLASS=Stream FORCE=true on the local version, the heroku version no longer works. When I use the command on the heroku version, the local version no longer works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `Tire::Model::Callbacks` module in your `Stream` model it should be deleted automatically.

If you want to run it manually from controller following code should probably work.

```
@stream.destroy
@stream.tire.update_index
```

Comment: I have Callbacks included in the model. When I use your code, I receive the Couldn't find all Streams with 'id': (1, 2, 3, 32) (found 3 results, but was looking for 4) error once but on refresh it is fine

Comment: Can you add also your model code? This is quite weird, when I tried that code in rails console it worked perfectly. Also you should look into elasticsearch log, if it tries destroy data from elasticsearch index.

Comment: Just to be sure, in your elasticsearch log you should se something like this `curl -X DELETE "http://localhost:9200/streams/stream/1"` if you try destroy some `@stream`.

Comment: I can't find my elasticsearch log anywhere

Comment: Add `Tire.configure { logger 'log/elasticsearch.log' }` to initializers, then you will find it in your rails app log directory.

Comment: The code to remove the indexes works. I think I am having problems because my local development database and my production database on heroku are both configured in the tire.rb file to the same bonsai url. So when I do the reindex rake command in either development or production, the other one will have an inconsistency with the elasticsearch indexes. I have tried to use url "http://localhost:9200" in my tire.rb file when I just want to work on local development but I get a connection refused error for some reason.

Comment: Oops I forgot have elastic search running locally. $elasticsearch -f starts it.

Comment: Yes, that could explain a lot. You definitely should use different databases for production and development environments.

Comment: I am having the same problem with the "Couldn't find all the <Model> with 'id'(1,2,3,32)(found 3 results, but was looking for 4)' error.  I see the index being updated from the elasticsearch log file.  It appears to be a timing issue for me as I see the delete in the log file but get the stated error message after the redirect to the index page.  If I refresh the associated index page after getting the error message then it displays correctly.  Similar problem with creates where the index page does not display the new record until after a refresh.

Comment: Can you show some code how is it all used? It looks, that you trying do it in some background job or so.